# Incorrect char from file

Tags: c++, text-files, iostream, fstream, cout

I have the following .txt file:

test.txt

```
1,2,5,6
```

Passing into a small C++ program I made through command line as follows:

```
./test test.txt
```

Source is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int temp =0;
    ifstream file;
    file.open(argv[1]);

    while(!file.eof())
    {
        temp=file.get();
            file.ignore(1,',');
        cout<<temp<<' ';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

For some reason my output is not `1 2 5 6` but `49 50 53 54`. What gives?

UPDATE:

Also, I noticed there is another implementation of `get()`. If I define `char temp` then I can do `file.get(temp)` and that will also save me converting ASCII representation. However I like using `while (file >> temp)` so I will be going with that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

49 is the ascii code for digit 49-48 = 1.

`get()` gives you a character (character code).

by the way, `eof()` only *becomes* true after a failed read attempt, so the code you show,

```
while(!file.eof())
{
    temp=file.get();
        file.ignore(1,',');
    cout<<temp<<' ';
}
```

will possibly display one extraneous character at the end.

the conventional loop is

```
while( file >> temp )
{
     cout << temp << ' ';
}
```

where the expression `file >> temp` reads in one number and produces a reference to `file`, and where that `file` objected is converted to `bool` as if you had written

```
while( !(file >> temp).fail() )
```

Answer (score 1):

`temp` is an int. So you see the encoded ascii values after casting the char to an int.

Answer (score 0):

This does not do what you think it does:

```
while(!file.eof())
```

This is covered in [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5605125/78845), so I won't cover it in this answer.

Try:

```
char c;
while (file >> c)
{
    // [...]
}
```

...instead. Reading in a `char` rather than an `int` will also save you having to convert the [ascii](/questions/tagged/ascii) representation (ASCII value 49 is `1`, *etc...*).

Answer (score 0):

For the record, and despite this being the nth duplicate, here's how this code might look in idiomatic C++:

```
for (std::string line; std::getline(file, line); )
{
    std::istringstream iss(line);

    std::cout << "We read:";

    for (std::string n; std::getline(iss, line, ','); )
    {
        std::cout << " " << n;

        // now use e.g. std::stoi(n)
    }

    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

If you don't care about lines or just have one line, you can skip the outer loop.